# Show notification on status bar for media player in android

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, http-live-streaming

I am streaming an audio in android and try to play in background also. But i need to  show some notification in status bar with some play button that the music is running how can i do that...

Answer (score 1):

Start from [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). There is nothing complicated - provide text, icon and show notification for user

Comment: What do you mean real example? In docs there is screenshots and step by step instruction for writing code. If I would write how I implement notifications - it will be almost the same as in oficial docs.